# Modals sobrepondo a Tela

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

> Os meus modals eles estão sobrepondo a tela quando eu faço o teste em tempo real via github, caso o teste seja feito em minha própria
>   máquina abrindo o arquivo .html eles ficam perfeitos.

- **GITHUB**

> [image: Github]

- **MINHA MÁQUINA**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   [image: Minha MÁquina]

- **CÓDIGO HTML**

> https://codepaste.net/rxjxq3

- **CÓDIGO CSS**

> https://codepaste.net/4vxm5u

**OBS: Não foram postados os códigos aqui, pois ultrapassou o limite de linhas.**

Comment: Fez upload corretamente de todos os arquivos para o GitHub? Se não me engano, há um `delay` de update. Tente rodar em um servidor local, como Wamp ou Xampp.

Comment: Dei uma olhada diretamente no GitHub, ao abrir o console recebo várias mensagens de erro: http://prntscr.com/fqh4i1 Veja se o problema não está aqui.

Comment: @DanielBonifácio , eu estou hospedando isso no github pages. Ele dá algum problema com esse código de modals do bootstrap?